# Yet another .ini parser for AutoHotKey

Tags: parsing, autohotkey

I decided to learn a little about AutoHotKey, to practice a little and learn about classes.

I ended up writting a basic ini file parser.

```
Class Ini {
    ini_file := ""
    ini_data := {}

    __New(ini_file)
    {
        if ini_file
        {
            this.ini_file := ini_file


            Try
            {
                FileGetAttrib, attrs, %ini_file%
            }
            catch e
            {}

            If (attrs) and (!InStr(attrs, "D"))
            {
                this.ini_data := new Ini.IniData(ini_file)
            }
            else if attrs
            {
                Throw, "Please specify a file name, not a directory"
            }
            else
            {
                this.ini_data := new Ini.IniData("")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ini_data := new Ini.IniData("")
        }
    }

    IniFile()
    {
        return this.ini_file
    }

    LoadString(ini_text)
    {
        data := InI.IniParser.ParseFromString(ini_text)
        this.ini_data.LoadData(data)
    }
    
    Save()
    {
        if this.ini_file
        {
            return InI.IniWriter.Write(this.ini_file, this.ini_data)
        }
        else
        {
            Throw, "Please use SaveFile(ini_file) instead"
        }
    }

    SaveFile(ini_file)
    {
        if ini_file
        {
            return InI.IniWriter.Write(ini_file, this.ini_data)
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Save()
        }
    }
    
    Get(value_name, section_name, default_value)
    {
        if !value_name
        {
            Throw, "Value name can't be empty."
        }

        if this.ini_data.HasValue(value_name, section_name)
        {
            return this.ini_data.GetValue(value_name, section_name)
        }
        else
        {
            return default_value
        }
    }
    
    Set(value_name, section_name, value)
    {
        if !value_name
        {
            Throw, "Value name can't be empty."
        }

        this.ini_data.SetValue(value_name, value, section_name)
    }
    
    Delete(value_name, section_name)
    {
        if value_name
        {
            this.ini_data.DeleteValue(value_name, section_name)
        }
        else
        {
            this.DeleteSection(section_name)
        }
    }

    DeleteSection(section_name)
    {
        this.ini_data.DeleteSection(section_name)
    }

    Exists(value_name, section_name)
    {
        return this.ini_data.HasValue(value_name, section_name)
    }

    ExistsSection(section_name)
    {
        return this.ini_data.HasSection(section_name)
    }

    Sections()
    {
        return this.ini_data.ListSections()
    }


    class IniData {
        data := {}

        __New(ini_file)
        {
            if(ini_file)
            {
                this.LoadData(Ini.IniParser.Parse(ini_file))
            }
        }

        LoadData(data)
        {
            this.data := data
        }


        ListSections()
        {
            sections := []

            for key, value in this.data
            {
                sections.Push(key)
            }

            return sections
        }

        HasSection(section_name)
        {
            return this.data.HasKey(section_name)
        }

        CreateSection(section_name)
        {
            if !this.HasSection(section_name)
            {
                this.data[section_name] := {}
            }
        }

        GetSection(section_name)
        {
            if !this.HasSection(section_name)
            {
                return []
            }

            return this.data[section_name]
        }

        DeleteSection(section_name)
        {
            if this.HasSection(section_name)
            {
                this.data[section_name].Remove()
            }
        }



        ListValues(section_name)
        {
            values := []

            for key, value in this.GetSection(section_name)
            {
                values.Push(key)
            }

            return values
        }

        HasValue(value_name, section_name)
        {
            return ((this.HasSection(section_name)) and (this.data[section_name].HasKey(value_name)))
        }

        SetValue(value_name, value, section_name)
        {
            if !this.HasSection(section_name)
            {
                this.CreateSection(section_name)
            }

            this.data[section_name][value_name] := value
        }

        GetValue(value_name, section_name)
        {
            if !this.HasValue(value_name, section_name)
            {
                this.SetValue(value_name, "", section_name)
            }

            return this.data[section_name][value_name]
        }

        DeleteValue(value_name, section_name)
        {
            if this.HasValue(value_name, section_name)
            {
                this.data[section_name][value_name].Remove()
            }
        }
    }

    class IniParser {
        Parse(ini_file)
        {
            data := {}
            section_name := ""

            Loop, read, %ini_file%
            {
                if !A_LoopReadLine ; empty line - must ignore
                {
                    Continue
                }

                parsed_line := InI.IniParser.ParseLine(A_LoopReadLine, section_name)

                if !parsed_line
                {
                    continue
                }

                section_name := parsed_line.section

                if !data[section_name]
                {
                    data[section_name] := {}
                }
                
                data[section_name] := InI.IniParser.ParsedLineIntoData(parsed_line, data[section_name])
            }

            return data
        }

        ParseFromString(ini_text)
        {
            data := {}
            section_name := ""

            Loop, parse, ini_text, `n, `r
            {
                if !A_LoopField ; empty line - must ignore
                {
                    Continue
                }

                parsed_line := InI.IniParser.ParseLine(A_LoopField, section_name)

                if !parsed_line
                {
                    continue
                }

                section_name := parsed_line.section

                if !data[section_name]
                {
                    data[section_name] := {}
                }
                
                data[section_name] := InI.IniParser.ParsedLineIntoData(parsed_line, data[section_name])
            }

            return data
        }

        ParsedLineIntoData(parsed_line, data)
        {
            if !parsed_line.name
            {
                return {}
            }
            
            data[parsed_line.name] := parsed_line.value
            return data
        }

        ParseLine(ini_line, current_section_name)
        {
            ; can't have values with newlines
            line := StrReplace(RegExReplace(ini_line, "^\s+|\s+$"), "`r`n", " ")
            char := SubStr(line, 1, 1)

            if (char == "[") ; section identified - needs parenthesis
            {
                section_name := InI.IniParser.ParseSection(line)
                return {"section": section_name, "name": "", "value": ""}
            }
            else
            {
                ; otherwise, must be a value
                value := InI.IniParser.ParseValue(line)
                return {"section": current_section_name, "name": value[1], "value": value[2]}
            }
        }

        ParseSection(line)
        {
            ; goal - trim the [] from the line
            return RegExReplace(line, "^\[|\]$")
        }

        ParseValue(line)
        {
            ; only want to split once, to preserve any values
            values := StrSplit(line, [" = ", " =", "= ", "="], " `t", 2)
            return values
        }
    }

    class IniWriter {
        Write(ini_file, ini_data)
        {
            Try
            {
                file := FileOpen(ini_file, "w")

                ; everything without a section is to be stored at the top
                if ini_data.HasSection("")
                {
                    file.Write(InI.IniWriter.MakeValues(ini_data.GetSection("")) . "`r`n")
                }

                for key, section_name in ini_data.ListSections()
                {
                    ; skips the "" section, since it was added before
                    if !section_name
                    {
                        continue
                    }

                    section := ini_data.GetSection(section_name)
                    if section
                    {
                        line := "[" . section_name . "]`r`n" . InI.IniWriter.MakeValues(section) . "`r`n"
                        
                        file.Write(line)
                    }
                }

                file.Close()

                return True
            }
            catch e
            {
                return False
            }
        }

        MakeValues(data)
        {
            ini_text := ""

            for key, value in data
            {
                ini_text .= key . "=" . value . "`r`n"
            }

            return ini_text
        }
    }
}
```

---

The idea is to write a basic and simple to use parser, as an alternative to spamming multiple [`IniRead`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm) and [`IniWrite`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm) to save/read settings.

---

### Usage:

The idea is to simply set the file name in the contructor and everything happens.

An example:

```
ini := new Ini(A_ScriptDir . "\a.ini")

ini.Set("ticks", "settings", A_TickCount)

ini.Save()
```

Opens the file `a.ini`, parses it, sets `A_TickCount` in the `ticks` value in the `[settings]` section.

This generates an ini file that looks like this:

```
[settings]
ticks = 123456789
```

You can get values, get a list of all sections, remove values and sections and even load contents from a string.

You can also include this file with an `#include`.

This parser supports no sections (the section name will be an empty string), but doesn't support comments.
Comment support isn't something I'm considering.

---

I've tested reading and writting back with a few files, and everything seems to be working fine.

Currently, the code feels like a massive mess, and if possible, I would like some additional tips on cleaning up a little.

Anything else I should consider, to improve this code?